# Deploy SQL database to Azure is failing

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to deploy a SQL Server database to Azure. In SSMS, I right click the database and choose `Tasks > Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database`.

This database isn't part of source control or anything, and in the properties, I selected compatibility level 140 (SQL Server 2017).

However, I keep getting the error below when deploying it. What am I doing wrong? I was able to deploy this exact database in the past without issues.

[image: SSMS error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please forget about SSMS for migrating databases to Azure SQL Database. Use [Microsoft Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) for this task. This tool is the easiest way to migrate to Azure SQL Database. It performs an assessment first, then it migrates your databases to Azure.

Comment: what a wonderful tool...not sure how I haven't run into it sooner! thanks!!

Comment: I am glad you have that user experience with the tool.

Comment: Its a fine tool, but is extremely slow.

Comment: @GerardoBuenrostroGonzález Try Azure Data Studio also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/azure-sql-migration-extension?view=sql-server-ver16